# Why does this piece of code make my page blank?

Tags: php

My page was working fine until I added this piece of code and I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['credclick'])){ 
$amount=$_POST['credits']
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points = points+".$amount." WHERE id = '".$username."'");
echo"<p>Credits Added</p>";
}
?>
```

$username is defined from the session at the top of the page.

```
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: 1. Please activate error reporting and try again. 2. Please read about SQL injection.

Comment: You really need to Google `SQL injection`. Your site is easily hackable like this.

Comment: [Don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1883647), and look at your error logs.

Comment: basic debugging: if you get a blank page, then php blew up, and you've got display_errors/error_reporting turned off. They should NEVER be off on a devel/debug system.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^ **Which you are not doing** ^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 4):

Syntax error likely:
Add a semi-colon at the end of `$amount=$_POST['credits']` to indicate end of statement.

Change `$amount=$_POST['credits']` to `$amount=$_POST['credits'];`

As other have indicated, you are susceptible to malicious sql injection, so to fix that, a) stop using the `mysql_` and use `PDO` or `mysqli_` or at the very least sanitize your statement with something like:

`$amount = htmlentities($_POST['credits'], ENT_QUOTES);` or `$amount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['credits']);`

Best practice though is to switch db connection type.

Comment: At least point out that you added the `;`. A quick glance would look like the two versions are identical. But +1 for catching the error.

Comment: Agreed, you should *always* explain differences between code snippets, even if it would appear obvious to you.

Comment: Yeah, true. Sometimes I take those little things for granted that everyone should pick up on...

Comment: It doesn't add to the column in my database any help?

using code

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting` turned on? If not, turn it on. You may have a syntax error in your sql statement.